# How do I line up the tasks on the right side of parallel tasks in flowchart.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael, flowchart

Am cross-posting this from flowchart.js github [issues](https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js/issues/154) to garner more attention

The image below posted is what actually gets generated by flowchart.js.

#### Actual image

[image]
I am using quite a fair bit of parallel tasks and I noticed that they don't line up together.

#### What I expected

The right hand side elements are vertically aligned

#### Details

My purposes of having those IO or subroutine is because they further elaborate what's happening at the individual processes.

Am I using parallel tasks correctly? Is there a way to make the parallel tasks on the right aligned?

My code that I wrote to generate the actual image

```
        st=>start
        e=>end
        vendor_submit=>parallel: Vendor Submit Files
        files=>inputoutput: 1 Excel per quotation
        1 PDF per quotation
        1 Excel as summary
        identify_type=>operation: PSS1 identify ASP/3PP/RES 
        check_completeness=>parallel: PSS1 check for completeness
        data_submitted=>inputoutput: quote no.
        quote value
        project
        enter_quotation_data=>parallel: PSS1 enter quotation data
        and assign PSS2
        notify_vendor=>subroutine: email notification to vendor
        breakdown_persite=>parallel: PSS2 breakdown per site
        breakdown_data_submitted=>inputoutput: Quotation Excel
        Quotation PDF
        Summary Excel

        st->vendor_submit
        vendor_submit(path1, right)->files
        vendor_submit(path2, bottom)->identify_type
        identify_type->check_completeness
        check_completeness(path1, right)->data_submitted
        check_completeness(path2, bottom)->enter_quotation_data
        enter_quotation_data(path1, right)->notify_vendor
        enter_quotation_data(path2, bottom)->breakdown_persite
        breakdown_persite(path1, right)->breakdown_data_submitted
        breakdown_persite(path2, bottom)->e
```

Comment: This is the expected graph image or the actual? You should add expected and actual details to help people understand the issue better

Comment: That's the actual. I have also written a bit more explicitly what I expected. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the below pull request

https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js/issues/115

What you need is `align-next=no`. Below is the updated graph code

```
st=>start
e=>end
vendor_submit(align-next=no)=>parallel: Vendor Submit Files
files=>inputoutput: 1 Excel per quotation
1 PDF per quotation
1 Excel as summary
identify_type=>operation: PSS1 identify ASP/3PP/RES 
check_completeness(align-next=no)=>parallel: PSS1 check for completeness
data_submitted=>inputoutput: quote no.
quote value
project
enter_quotation_data(align-next=no)=>parallel: PSS1 enter quotation data
and assign PSS2
notify_vendor=>subroutine: email notification to vendor
breakdown_persite(align-next=no)=>parallel: PSS2 breakdown per site
breakdown_data_submitted=>inputoutput: Quotation Excel
Quotation PDF
Summary Excel

st->vendor_submit
vendor_submit(path1, right)->files
vendor_submit(path2, bottom)->identify_type
identify_type->check_completeness
check_completeness(path1, right)->data_submitted
check_completeness(path2, bottom)->enter_quotation_data
enter_quotation_data(path1, right)->notify_vendor
enter_quotation_data(path2, bottom)->breakdown_persite
breakdown_persite(path1, right)->breakdown_data_submitted
breakdown_persite(path2, bottom)->e
```

And below is the output of the same

[image: Update flow chart]

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what i needed.